# Formatting mathematical expressions

Tags: java, android

I'm currently in the process of designing my own derivative calculator for Android using Java. I have seen other apps read mathematical expressions typed in by the user and it formats it in a way that it looks like it's written on paper.

I'm trying to see if there is a way that my app could do that as well.
For example, I could type an expression square rooted or taken to the power of an integer and it would appear not as "sqrt(x+3) or x^3" like it literally looks on the console, but formatted accordingly based on what is written. I know that I could just use Unicode for a square root, which is \u221A, but I specifically am looking for the functionality like in the example picture below.

[image: Example Expression in Derivative Calculator App]

Is it possible using Java or will I have to switch to using something else? I don't know where to start looking for a solution. I've tried looking for solutions online but there's nothing that matches what I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this article on [custom drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) is a good entry point.

Answer (score 0):

The [github.com/jianzhongli/MathView](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView) library seems like it should work for you - here is an example rendering of your first equations with the code below:

[image]

This is set in a layout but the library provides programmatic ways of doing same.  This example uses the MathJax engine and the library also supports KaTeX.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="f(x) = sqrt(x/(x+2))"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/formula_one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
        android:id="@+id/formula_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1"
        app:text="\\begin{align} f(x) &amp; = \\sqrt{\\frac{x}{x+2}} \\\\ &amp; = \\frac{\\sqrt{x}}{\\sqrt{x+2}} \\end{align}"
        app:engine="MathJax"
        >
    </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## MathJax

As you can see the formula is defined in the `app:text` field of the `MathView` element:

```
app:text="\\begin{align} f(x) &amp; = \\sqrt{\\frac{x}{x+2}} \\\\ &amp; = \\frac{\\sqrt{x}}{\\sqrt{x+2}} \\end{align}"
```

## build.gradle(app)

To use MathView just add this to your app gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
}
```

## Programmatically

You could accomplish the same result using code in activity:

```
MathView mv = findViewById(R.id.formula_one);
mv.setText("\\begin{align} f(x) &amp; = \\sqrt{\\frac{x}{x+2}} \\\\ &amp; = \\frac{\\sqrt{x}}{\\sqrt{x+2}} \\end{align}");
```

## Reference

Here's a starter guide to using MathJax:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/25048#25048