# How to use mathematical symbol in edit text of android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

I am developing an application and I want to use several mathematical symbols like integration sign, differentiation symbol, write some number as superscript (to give powers), etc... Can anybody help me out how can i use them?

Comment: I'm guessing that the simple use of html symbols is not powerful enough for you? When you ad &#8747; to any string in a TextView for example a Integral should appear. [more symbols](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/)

Comment: Consider MathJax and an android library supporting it: https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView . For an example see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61447002/2711811

Comment: Thanku for your help!!

Comment: I want to ask that how can i learn MathJax codes?

Comment: Start here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Just to add there are also a range of symbols inbuilt to android studio and you can use them like: ```String mytemp = tempvalue.gettemp().toString + "\u2103" ;``` Where the u2103 is the degrees symbol in C. There is a range of these symbols.